# Angular library for dynamic 3D house modeling

Tags: library, 3d, angular

I need a library that I can use with Angular (desirably open source) in order to give the user the ability to modify a house design. If there is not such library maybe some software that I can embed inside my code.

I found a webpage that has this exact functionality. Here is a short video from them on youtube explaining the functionality - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JtxsK-lFow

Any recommendation is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck?